# Unknown column 'Array' in 'where clause' but variable is a string, not an array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I am getting an error that is suggesting that my variable in my WHERE clause is an Array, but when I use gettype() on it, it returns that it is in fact a string. At first it was an array, and I researched it, and figured out how to turn into string, but for some reason it is still thinking it is an array... here is code:

```
$params = array(':user_id' => $user_id, ':device_token'=>$post['device_token'], ':last_sync_time'=>$post['last_sync_time']);
$get_group = $db->prepare("SELECT group_id 
FROM users 
WHERE id = '{$user_id}'");
$get_group->execute($params);
$group_id = $get_group->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //Gets the group id for the user downloading slides
$group_id = implode($group_id);
```

then

```
$get_group_slides = $db->prepare("SELECT audiourl,color,font_name,font_size,haveaudio,imageurl,isvideo,onlytext,slider_id,videourl,created 
FROM admin_slides 
WHERE group_id = $group_id AND created > '{$last_admin_sync}' 
ORDER BY created 
ASC LIMIT 20");
$get_group_slides->execute($params); //will get slides for assigned user group
```

$get_group_slides is what is giving me the error, and when I remove the $group_id variable from the WHERE clause, error goes away... I echo $group_id and it shows the correct value.. gettype($group_id) returns string... Any ideas?

EDIT: I just tested again and I must have done something wrong, so it echoes that the variable is a string, but for some reason when I echo the variable now, it echoes "Array".

Comment: you have to have a `glue` to implode arrays `$group_id = implode($YOUR_GLUE,$group_id);`

Comment: From my understanding if you do not include glue it will default to an empty string, which is fine in this case because the array contains only one element... Either way I tried it just in case and am still getting the same result :(

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using implode(), I just used $group_id = $group_id[0]['group_id'], and now it is working! There are too many ways to do try and do the same thing -.-'